# Multi dimensional integration with quadpack results in recursive call to nonrecursive procedure 'dqage'

Tags: fortran

I am attempting to perform a 2D integral numerically using the [quadpack double library](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/f_src/quadpack_double/quadpack_double.html). Since this website does not have a Latex engine integrated I attach a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFx0v.png) with the math.

I also attach below my implementation of this operation in the `test_module` module.

```
module test_module
  use f90_kind ! defines dp
  use physconst ! defines pi
  use global_variables ! defines the variables for quadpack
  use csv_file ! allows me to write to a csv file

  implicit none

  real(dp) :: a, b, c ! parameters I want to set

contains

  real(dp) function multi_val_func(theta)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: theta

    multi_val_func = exp(theta**2 + c*theta)

  end function multi_val_func

  real(dp) function theta_integral(phi)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: phi

    c = phi*(a+b)

    ! Quadpack variables
    epsabs = 1.0E-14_dp
    epsrel = 0.0E0_dp
    key    = 6
    ilow   = 0.0E0_dp
    ihigh  = 2.0E0_dp*pi

    call dqage(multi_val_func, ilow, ihigh, epsabs, epsrel, key, limit, &
               res, abserr, neval, ier, alist, blist, rlist, elist, iord, last)

    theta_integral = res

  end function theta_integral

  subroutine phi_integral(final_result)
    real(dp),intent(out) :: final_result

    a = 1.0E0_dp
    b = 1.0E0_dp

    ! Quadpack variables
    epsabs = 1.0E-14_dp
    epsrel = 0.0E0_dp
    key    = 6
    ilow   = 0.0E0_dp
    ihigh  = pi

    call dqage(theta_integral, ilow, ihigh, epsabs, epsrel, key, limit, &
               res, abserr, neval, ier, alist, blist, rlist, elist, iord, last)

    final_result = res

    print *, final_result

  end subroutine phi_integral

end module test_module
```

In the main file I define the `result` variable and thereafter `call phi_integral(result)`. I compile this code using the following makefile

```
FFLAGS = -O0 -fcheck=all -ffree-line-length-none

debug:
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/f90_kind.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/physconst.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/global_variables.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(extlib_qp)/quadpack_double.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(extlib_csv)/csv_file.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/multi_var_integration.f90
    gfortran -c $(FFLAGS) $(srcdir)/main.f90
    gfortran *.o -o debug -lblas -llapack
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

The code compiles but when I run it I receive the following error:

```
Fortran runtime error: Recursive call to nonrecursive procedure 'dqage'

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x103a28d3d
#1  0x103a299f5
#2  0x103a29fd6
#3  0x1039f94b6
#4  0x1039dee59
#5  0x1039fad68
#6  0x1039f9948
#7  0x1039dec7d
#8  0x1039def61
#9  0x1039defa3
```

Any suggestion for dealing with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand what "Recursive call to nonrecursive procedure" means, and what the implications are? You are likely better off trying to use a quadrature routine/package which is designed for 2-D integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every subroutine or function in Fortran is re-entrant or, as Fortran calls it, "recursive". Before Fortran 2018 a subroutine that can be called, when already inside itself (even if indirectly) must be marked by the `recursive` attribute.

Even if a subroutine is marked that way, it may not work as expected if it contains static (saved) data or if it uses global (common blocks, module) variables.

I cannot immediately see any such static data used in http://www.netlib.no/netlib/quadpack/dqage.f so it might actually work after adding `recursive`.

However, as francescalus  pointed out, you should be better off with a dedicated 2d quadrature library.

Answer (score 0):

The `theta` integral can be done via the error function `erf`. See [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20exp%28x%5E2%20%2B%202*x*y*C%29%20dx%20for%20x%3D0..pi).

The result of that is a function of one variable `phi` which can be evaluated via `quadpack`. Thus, you don't need a multidimensional integral routine after all.